# If spectrum of a ring is connected, then the ring is integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If the spectrum of a ring is connected, then will the ring be an integral domain?

The spectrum is set of all prime ideals. Given the Zariski topology, how is it that connectedness of the set of prime ideals imply that there are no zero divisors? I think the nilradical of the ring is a subset of the spectrum of the ring. I am unable to start the problem. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: No. Consider for instance the ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(XY)$. It’s not integral but its spectrum is connected, as its subspace of maximal elements (which is dense) is the reunion of two intersecting lines in the Zariski topology. There’s also a more obvious obstruction in that the spectrum of a ring does not notice nilpotent elements, so no topological property of the spectrum (apart from being empty) can make sure the ring is reduced.

Comment: @Mindlack could you elaborate more on the topology of the ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(XY)$ and your overall comment?

Comment: For interest: Clopen sets of Spec$(A)$ are in one to one correspondence with idempotents of $A$, so $A$ is connected if and only if $A$ has no non-trivial idempotents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of commutative rings that are connected but are not domains.

Local rings that are not domains are a very large class of that type.

But there are non-local examples too, like $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Comment: Here is the [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=38&L=8) for commutative, connected, nondomain rings.